# how can I move elements of a datatable

Tags: html, css

I want the excel and pdf icons to appear before the show log,

I leave you an image of what I want to do so that you understand me

```
$(document).ready(function() {

              $('#dt_articulos').DataTable({
               "order": [],    
               "info": true,       
               "autoWidth": false,
               "responsive": true,
               "language": {
                   "url": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>static/js/datatables_spanish.json"
               },
               "dom": "Blfrtip",
                "buttons":[
                    {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                        titleAttr: 'EXCEL'

                    },
                    {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>',
                    titleAttr: 'PDF',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                    attr:  {
                      id: 'botonpdf'
                    }
                }],

            });
        } );
```

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmNwR.png) is the image

Comment: Did you try to move them? It's hard to understand whether you've tried and are having problems or you're asking how to do it?

Comment: @darenSweeney I have tried to do it but I don't know how to do it so that the Excel and PDF icons are below and that of showing records below, like the image I have set.

Comment: `I have tried to do it...` can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Of course I have edited the classes of the pdf and excel buttons.

Comment: .buttons-html5, .buttons-print{
    font-size: 34px !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

Comment: Can you post the link to that page? I can help then.